# .Net Application Release Procedure and VSS

Tags: .net-3.5, visual-sourcesafe

We have around 20 Application developers in our team.

All the application code is in the VSS.

Developers have their local copies and make changes and then check the files to VSS.

Team leads will look into the code and run it from their machines and if everything looks good they will move the code to QA Server.

QA after testing if approves all the files are checked and the release engineer will get latest version from VSS and compile and move the files to staging.

UAT will be done on the staging and if approved, release engineer will copy all the files from staging and move it to Production.

Oflate we are having issues with this approach as developers checked-in some files in the VSS while it was going to staging that were not supposed to be released to staging.

We use VS.net 2008 as IDE we don't have team foundation server and Visual source safe is our Source control database.

Please do suggest how we can improve our release mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [labels in VSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e8x236w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - label releases and this way you can alway go back to a known state of code.

That is, suppose you are ready for some code to go into QA - at this moment, label the whole branch to a version numbers, say "Version 1.1".

When it is time to promote to UAT/Production, get all the items labeled "Version 1.1" - ensuring a consistent QA process with the exact same code.

When your next version of the code is ready for QA, label it "Version 1.2"... etc.. etc.. etc.

You will however need to decide how to deal with bug fixes.

Comment: Oded, thanks for your prompt response. The whole issue we are facing is with the bug fixes. Application is in production for the past few years and there is on going maintanance.

Comment: @acadia - Again, tagging can help. If you don't _already_ have this (or similar) solution, there isn't a way to retrofit it. With bug fixes, you need to decide if they need to be ported to the latest version or not and tag/promote accordingly. To be honest, VSS is poor at this kind of thing. Do yourself and your team a favor and look at Subversion as an alternative source control management system.